# Getting a list of all churches in a certain state using Python

Tags: python, automation, web-crawler, pseudocode, street-address

I am pretty good with Python, so pseudo-code will suffice when details are trivial. Please get me started on the task - how do go about crawling the net for the snail mail addresses of churches in my state. Once I have a one liner such as "123 Old West Road #3 Old Lyme City MD 01234", I can probably parse it into City, State, Street, number, apt with enough trial and error. My problem is - if I use white pages online, then how do I deal with all the HTML junk, HTML tables, ads, etc? I do not think I need their phone number, but it will not hurt - I can always throw it out once parsed. Even if your solution is half-manual (such as save to pdf, then open acrobat, save as text) - I might be happy with it still. Thanks! Heck, I will even accept Perl snippets - I can translate them myself.

Comment: Thanks for the list of technologies. Now, which online directory provides the highest signal-to noise ratio? Also, what if the results span multiple pages? How can I click through them all using your technology of choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). It's a python library that simulates a browser, so you could crawl through the white pages (similarly to what you do manually).

In order to deal with the 'html junk' python has a library for that too: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup)
It is a lovely way to get the data you want out of HTML (of course it assumes you know a little bit about HTML, as you will still have to navigate the parse tree).

Update: As to your follow-up question on how to click through multiple pages. mechanize is a library to do just that. Take a closer look at their examples, esp. the follow_link method. As I said it simulates a browser, so 'clicking' can be realized quickly in python.

Comment: It was hard to choose the best answer. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2):

Try `lynx --dump <url>` to download the web pages. All the troublesome HTML tags will be stripped from the output, and all the links from the page will appear together.

Comment: Huh? If you're scraping different web sites with arbitrary layouts, the HTML is more likely to get in your way.

Comment: I would prefer scraping just one website if I can.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called *[Scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)* or web scraping.

If you do some [searches](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+web+scraping) on [python and scraping](http://www.packtpub.com/article/web-scraping-with-python), you may find a list of [tools](http://scrapy.org/) that will help.

(I have never used scrapy, but it's site looks promising :)

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup is a no brainer. Here's a site you might start at http://www.churchangel.com/. They have a huge list and the formatting is very regular -- translation: easy to setup BSoup to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

Python scripts might not be the best tool for this job, if you're just looking for addresses of churches in a geographic area.

The US census provides a data set of churches for use with geographic information systems. If finding all the `x` in a spatial area is a recurring problem, invest in learning a GIS. Then you can bring your Python skills to bear on many geographic tasks.

Comment: Do you have a link to this census data? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the dataset is called TIGER/Line and is available at
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2009/tgrshp2009.html

To start use it, read up on GIS concepts and grab a free GIS like QuantumGIS